# how to assign distinct values to distinct rows in a new column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to assign an atomic vector of values to an atomic vector composed of df rows:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(new_col= assign(c('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5'), c(10,25,35,45,50)))
```

However this code outputs the next error:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `new_col`.
> x Input `new_col` can't be recycled to size 8.
> i Input `new_col` is `assign(c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"), c(10, 25, 35, 45, 50))`.
> i Input `new_col` must be size 8 or 1, not 5.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> Además: Warning messages:
> 1: Problem with `mutate()` input `new_col`.
> i sólo el primer elemento es usado como nombre de variable
> i Input `new_col` is `assign(c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"), c(10, 25, 35, 45, 50))`.
> 2: In assign(c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"), c(10, 25, 35, 45, 50)) :
> sólo el primer elemento es usado como nombre de variable

The expected output could look like this:

```
# A1 10
# A1 10
# A2 25
# A3 35
# A4 45
# A4 45
# A5 50
# A5 50
```

## data

```
df <- data.frame(legend=c('A1','A1' ,'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A4', 'A5', 'A5'))
```

How could I adjust the pipeline?

Comment: to create a new column indexed to the original df rows

Comment: If you need to create a column, then it may be better to have a named vector or a tibble with key/value data and join `keydat <- tibble(legend = c('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5'),  value = c(10, 25, 35, 45, 50));
> left_join(df, keydat)`

Comment: `df$new <- c(10, 25, 35, 45, 50)[match(df$legend, c('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5'))]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `assign` is what you're looking for. You could do this with `recode`, which is also from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(new_col = recode(legend, A1 = 10, A2 = 25, A3 = 35, A4 = 45, A5 = 50))
```

Or with a named vector:

```
v <- c("A1" = 10, "A2" = 25, "A3" = 35, "A4" = 45, "A5" = 50)

df %>% 
  mutate(new_col = recode(legend, !!!v))

# OR

df %>% 
  mutate(new_col = v[legend])

# In base R

df$new_col <- v[df$legend]

# OR

within(df, new_col <- v[legend])
```

**Output**

```
  legend new_col
1     A1      10
2     A1      10
3     A2      25
4     A3      35
5     A4      45
6     A4      45
7     A5      50
8     A5      50
```

`assign` is used to assign a name to a value in a specified environment:

```
a <- 1
assign("a", 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` you can use a `merge`

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(legend=c('A1','A1' ,'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A4', 'A5', 'A5'))
setDT(df)
df2  <- data.table(legend = paste0("A", 1:5), value = c(10,25,35,45,50))

merge(df,df2, by = "legend")

  legend value
1     A1    10
2     A1    10
3     A2    25
4     A3    35
5     A4    45
6     A4    45
7     A5    50
8     A5    50
```

A similar result can be obtained using

```
df2[df, on = "legend"] #As in you_lookup_datable[table, on ="key_column"]
```